# The parametric ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ with known $x+y$ and $x\cdot y$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

$x$ and $y$ are in fact $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, the bigger and smaller eigenvalues of a parametric matrix $A'A$, and $t$ is a very small constant. I have that

$$
\begin{split}
x+y &= 1+ \frac{t^2}{2} \\
 xy &= \frac{t^2}{4}
\end{split}
$$

How would I prove that $\frac{x}{y}\ge \frac{1}{t}$? The solutions of the system are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a%20system%20of%20equations&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%2By%20%3D1%20%2Bt%5E2%2F2%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22solve%20a%20system%20of%20equations%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22x*y%20%3D%20t%5E2%2F4%22), but it gets pretty messy. Is there an elegant way to go about this?

Comment: does order of matrix is given?

Answer (score 0):

So $x=\frac{1}{4}(t^2+2+\sqrt{t^4+4})$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}(t^2+2-\sqrt{t^4+4})$,  $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{(t^2+2+\sqrt{t^4+4})^2}{4t^2}$ say $t>0$. 
To prove that  $$\dfrac{(t^2+2+\sqrt{t^4+4})^2}{4t}\ge 1\Leftrightarrow t^4+4+4t^2+t^4+4+2(t^2+2)(\sqrt{t^4+4})-4t\ge 0$$ but $t^2-t+1\ge 0$.